# Finding maximum value from each group set in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below scenario:
Input Data:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| ID    | Account   | Sub_Acct  | Email                         |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| 100   | AD        | AD1       | 123@xyz.com                   |
| 100   | AB        | AB1       | test@abc.com, 123@xyz.com     |
| 100   | AB        | AB2       | test@abc.com, 123@xyz.com     |
| 200   | CD        | CD1       | test.1@pqr.com, 123@abc.com   |
| 200   | AB        | AB1       | test.2@pqr.com                |
| 200   | CD        | CD2       | test.1@pqr.com, 123@abc.com   |
| 200   | AB        | AB2       | 123@abc.com                   |
| 200   | CD        | CD3       | test.1@pqr.com, 123@abc.com   |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to take count of individual accounts partitioned by IDs. Whichever account has maximum count, I want to display that respective account with single entry with column Sub_acct populated as NULL. Rest all other accounts should be populated with their respective Sub_acct values within that specific ID.

Email domains to be extracted from Email column. The email_domain column values of the secondary accounts (within specific ID) will have values from the primary account( i.e. maximum count).. Below is the expected output:

```
 ------- -------------------------------------------
| ID    | Account   | Sub_Acct  | Email_Domain      |
 ------- -------------------------------------------
| 100   | AB        |           | abc.com, xyz.com  |   
| 100   | AD        | AD1       | abc.com, xyz.com  |
| 200   | CD        |           | pqr.com, abc.com  |
| 200   | AB        | AB1       | pqr.com, abc.com  |
| 200   | AB        | AB2       | pqr.com, abc.com  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

I have edited this question. Sorry for the trouble caused.
Can someone pls help with the sql query in Oracle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the duplicates - e.g. the second and third rows in your input are identical, so the output is too, so you want all 8 rows output still? Also - are you including duplicates in the count; and how do you want to break ties?

Comment: @Alex.. Yes, there are duplicates in my input data and also, I want to preserve duplicates in the output.. and for your second concern, there won't be any scenario in my input data where there will be a tie.

Comment: Which oracle version are you using ?

Comment: It looks like the table isn't normalized. Your sample data suggests that an ID/Account combination always has the same Email. If this is the case, you should consider changing your data model. Then, you store multiple emails as comma-separated lists. This is okay, as long as you are always only interested in the list as a whole and never in a separate single email. If you are interested in the parts (e.g. you want to select all rows containing the email xyz.com), you'll have to remodel this, too.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Oracle 10...

```
    with rank1 as
    (
        select id, 
        account, 
        email, count(account) as account_count, 
        rank() over (partition by id order by count(account) desc) as order_rank
        from table1
        group by id, account, email
    )
    select t1.*, 
    r1.account as primary_account, 
    r1.email as primary_email
    from table1 t1
    join rank1 r1
      on r1.id = t1.id
    where r1.order_rank = 1
```

Comment: this works.. however, there is change in the ask. Sorry for the trouble. Can you pls check updated question and help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

In your table an ID/Account pair can occur multiple times. And in your example such a pair has always the same Email. Is this guaranteed to be so? If it is, then your table isn't normalized and you can get consistency problems in the future.

However, relying on this would make writing the query easy-peasy:

```
select
  t.id,
  t.account,
  t.email,
  s.primary_account,
  s.primary_email
from mytable
join
(
  select
    id,
    stats_mode(account) as primary_account,
    stats_mode(email) as primary_email
  from mytable
  group by id
) s on s.id = t.id
order by id, account;
```

(It would be even easier, supported Oracle `STATS_MODE OVER`, but it doesn't yet.)